# function not working correctly unless there is an alert

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

**The problem**
I am having is the following code will not update the tow select boxes "select1" and "select2", unless I have an alert immediately preceding the code.

**Background info** -
I am posting two variables to this page, "sel1val" and "sel2val", and I am assigning them to hidden input boxes with id's "sel1valtry" and "sel2valtry" respectively. I am assigning the values of these input boxes to the variables in the function and have named them "sel1val" and "sel2val". I can post more code if need be, but it is what I call "franken code"...haha! because I am a novice, it is assembled from many different styles of code.

**Objective** - what I am trying to achieve is to set two select boxes based upon the value of "sel1val" and "sel2val". The correct functionality is only obtained when I have an alert prior to the code.

**Methods I have tried** - I have left in some commented out code, to illustrate my attempts. I have been through many forums and that is where I got these ideas from. I suspect that the alert "reloads" the javascript part of the page, but I have no real basis for this. I have tried "document ready", variations of "window load", and even tried slowing things down with a delay, in case it was a timing issue. Each of the methods I have tried have resulted in the same outcome, whereby it only works with an alert.

I have achieved much success with my web based projects, and this would not have been possible without the invaluable resource in forums such as this one. I would like to thank anyone that has ever provided input/solutions, as without this I would never have been able to progress.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//  $(document).ajaxSuccess(function(){
//    alert("AJAX request successfully completed");
//  });
//$(window).load(function()
//window.onload = function()
//$(function ()
//Code goes here
//alert("got here");
//{
var sel1val = $("#sel1valtry").val()
var sel2val = $("#sel2valtry").val()

if (sel2val)
{
//alert("will not work without this alert"+sel1val);    

//$("#select1").delay(2000).val(sel1val);
//$("#select1").val(sel1val);
$("#select1").prop('value',sel1val);
//  var element = document.getElementById('select1');
//    element.value = sel1val;
dochange('selection2', sel1val)
//var element = document.getElementById('select2');
//  element.value = sel2val;
alert("will not work without this alert"+sel2val);  
$("#select2").val(sel2val);
}
//}
});
//}
```

Comment: Does the $("#select1").prop('value',sel1val); work without the alert ? then there is something at odd in the dochange() function.

Answer (score 3):

It seems like the `dochange` function is using some asynchronous API (like an AJAX call for example) which is setting value to the `sel2val` variable in its success callback. But since AJAX is asynchronous, this function returns immediately, not waiting for the server to return a response. By putting an alert you are blocking the execution of the next line of code and leaving enough time for the AJAX call to complete and assign a value to the `sel2val` variable.

The proper way to fix your code is to provide a callback to this function where you will perform the necessary actions:

```
dochange('selection2', sel1val, function(result) {
    $("#select2").val(result);
});
```

And in your `dochange` function you will invoke this callback in the success event of your AJAX call.

Comment: Exactly. I agree with your answer.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your responses. the function dochange, is an ajax function, but it is populating a dynamic dropdown list. sel2val is being posted from another page. I have three dynamic dropdown boxes on the main page. I go to another page to submit some data to the database, and then when I return to this main page, I want to set the drop down boxes as they were when I left the page. when I am calling dochange at this point I am trying to simulate the selection of the first drop down list as if it had been selected with the mouse.