# javascript AJAX call causing a timing problem

Tags: javascript, ajax, callback

Program A has a form which submits to program B.  The program A form has an input :

```
<input type = 'hidden' name = 'token' id = 'token' value = ''>
```

The value is set in a javascript function tkn() which is called by program A.  The call:

```
<input type    = 'button'
       value   = 'continue'                  
       onclick = 'tkn()'>
```

The function tkn() calls an API function which returns the token.  A callback function handles success or failure of the call.  If there is success the callback executes

```
document.getElementById('token').value = response.id;
```

and then submits program A

```
var theform = document.getElementById('token');
alert('theform is ' + theform);
theform.submit();
```

Note the alert, which was put in there while I was debugging, to make sure the form was properly picked up before being submitted.

As long as the alert is there, everything is fine.  Program A is submitted to Program B, the token goes through to B and does whatever it is supposed to do.

However, if the alert is not there, the procedure fails, because the token is passed through to program B as a blank.

I found an explanation of the problem here, along with a solution I don't understand:   [function not working correctly unless there is an alert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16602742/function-not-working-correctly-unless-there-is-an-alert) . Apparently it is a timing problem because AJAX is asynchronous.  The alert gives the AJAX call time to complete.

He suggests that the solution is to provide a callback where "you will perform the necessary actions".  I have a callback function, but I don't know what are the "necessary actions" it should take to ensure that the AJAX call completes.  Here is the callback:

```
function tokenHandler( status, response ){

// (ie. if the "error" key exists in the response).
if (response.hasOwnProperty( "error" )){

alert(  "Something went wrong! + response.error.message);
return;
}

else{
  document.getElementById('token').value = response.id;
}

}//function tokenhandler
```

Can someone enlighten me about what "necessary actions" the callback function should take to make sure the AJAX call is complete?

In the comments it is suggested that putting the

```
document.getElementById('token').value = response.id;
```

in the callback is the correct thing, because we only get to the callback if the AJAX response is complete.  Well, that's where the line of code it -- in the callback function.  So maybe the problem isn't an AJAX timeing problem.  But it sure is true that the thing won't run without that alert.

Does anyone have any other suggestions?

API call:

```js
Stripe.createToken(
  {
    number: cardno, 
    exp_month: emth, 
    exp_year: eyr, 
    cvc: cvv, 
    address_zip: '19004' 
  }, 
  amount,
  tokenHandler,);

A SOLUTION HAS BEEN FOUND.  I put the submit into the callback function instead of in the main tkn() function.  That fixed the problem.  So after all it is a timing problem, but I think it is between the callback function and the main function.  I assumed the submit wouldn't happen until the callback was finished, but apparently that is not the case.
```

Comment: It would help if you showed the actual code that makes the AJAX call.

Comment: The "necessary actions" are the things you want to do with this token or the things you want to do **after** you get the token. In your case, I assume that you want to assign the token to the value property of the input tag: `document.getElementById('token').value = response.id;` - including error handling, of course. All this should be done inside the callback, since it gets executed **after** the response arrives from the server. The actual implementation depends among other things on whether you use plain JS or some third party library like jQuery to send the request.

Comment: @DonFoumare -- yes that line is in the callback.  So if what you say is true, the theory that the AJAX call is not completing must be wrong.  Then there is some other problem, and I haven't a clue what it is.

Comment: @ScottMarcus -- here is the call: Stripe.createToken(
              // The credit card information.
  { number: cardno,
    exp_month: emth,
    exp_year: eyr,
    cvc: cvv,  
                  address_zip: '19004'                
  }, 
             amount,// in cents 
       tokenHandler,              
 // The callback for our transaction token.
 );//create token

Comment: @BettyMock Do you use stripe.js from stripe.com?

Comment: @DonFoumare js.stripe.com

Comment: @DonFoumare  I FOUND A SOLUTION.  I put the submit into the callback function and now everything is working fine.  So it was after all a timing problem of some kind -- perhaps between the callback function and the tkn() function which invokes it.

Answer (score 0):

In the SO link you gave us, the answer says that the `alert()` paused the code. This makes the code work because AJAX does not run synchronously, which means the code does not wait for the AJAX call to finish. Therefore, the code and the AJAX run together and the AJAX hasn't given back the result when your code finishes running. But, `alert()`s stop the code from running temporarily until you click done, so the AJAX has time to finish.
Please add all of your JS code so I can see how it can be fixed. I will edit this once you do it.

You need to put your code inside the AJAX callback. Example:

```js
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
       // Code here
    }
};
xhr.open("GET", "filename", true);
xhr.send();
```

Maybe you could delete your `onclick` and add an event listener in the `// Code here`. Example:

```js
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
       document.getElementById("YourInput").addEventListener("click", function() {
           var theform = document.getElementById('token');
           alert('theform is ' + theform);
           theform.submit();
       });
    }
};
xhr.open("GET", "filename", true);
xhr.send();
```